# using fgets as non-blocking function c++

Tags: c++, nonblocking, fgets

I'm writing a program that reads in a loop from the stdin, using the function fgets, as follows:

```
while(fgets(buffer2, BUFFERSIZE , stdin) != NULL){
  //Some code  
}
```

I want my code to be non-blocking, that is: I don't want the program to hold on the 'fgets' line when there's no input at the moment from the user.
How can i do it?

Comment: I'd do this using separate threads.

Answer (score 6):

**`fgets()`** is a blocking function, it is meant to wait until data is available.

If you want to perform asynchronous I/O, you can use **`select()`**, **`poll()`**, or **`epoll()`**. And then perform a read from the file descriptor when there is data available.

These functions use the file descriptor of the FILE* handle, retrieved by:

```
int fd = fileno(f);
```

If you are using Unix or Linux, then one solution can be to mark the file descriptor used by the file to be non-blocking. Example:

```
#include <fcntl.h>  
FILE *handle = popen("tail -f /als/als_test.txt", "r"); 
int fd = fileno(handle);  
flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0); 
flags |= O_NONBLOCK; 
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
```

`fgets` should be non-blockng now and will return a null and set an error code for you.

Comment: Be careful with non-blocking I/O - from what I've read, it will work with pipes & ttys, but not regular files, so a `./prog < foo` will not perform non-blocking I/O. Depending on use, this might not matter. (See: http://davmac.org/davpage/linux/async-io.html#nonblockingopen)

Comment: @Thanatos It seems like non-blocking I/O isn't really relevant to regular files.  There's always data available until end of file, so reads will either return data or indicate EOF.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a proper POSIX environment, you can use `select()` or `poll()` to check for input on `stdin`'s descriptor before calling <strike>`fgets()`</strike>... `read()`.

Jan's comment below (thanks!) explains why you can't use `fgets()` with this approach... summarily, there's an extra layer of buffering in the `FILE` object, and data can already be waiting in though the `select()` finds nothing more on the file descriptor... preventing your program from responding in a timely way, and potentially hanging if some other system is waiting for a response to already sent data before sending more on `stdin`.

Comment: Not enough. You have to set the handle to non-blocking mode too (because you always need to read it out before calling select/poll again and that would block without) and you need to make sure you always read it out completely, because fgets reads more than it than returns, so you may still have data buffered, but select will wait, because the underlying descriptor does not have any more.

Comment: @Jan: yes, absolutely... silly me.  Which means - sans a non-blocking stdin - you must use `read()` instead of `fgets()` and handle the assembly of lines yourself (which tends - in my experience - to be either slightly fiddly or slightly inefficient)...

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

1. Run that loop in a separate thread.
2. Check if your OS supports some API for non-blocking IO.

Comment: or 3. select()/poll() etc...? :_)

Comment: @Tony - actually, it really depends on what @Dror needs and what is the whole code, because if it's a single thread, it could block on other place and never check for user input anymore.

Comment: @Kiril: certainly... but there's nothing to exclude 3 in the question as posed.  Cheers.

Comment: @Tony - of course, you're completely right (: And this didn't came to my mind at all (:

Comment: @Kiril: well, not so completely... Jan's corrected my oversight in a comment on my answer... round she goes :-).

Answer (score 0):

This would sound a little like overkill, but this is the one, that comes to my mind.

Use 2 different threads - one using this loop and waiting blocking ( I don't think that this could be done non-blocking). And when something is read, push it into a pipe.

Meanwhile, the other thread will do whatever it needs to do and check for data in the pipe from time to time ( apparently, you want this to be asynchronous, or at least I get it this way. If so, this means different threads )

But then, you'll need to synchronize the two threads very well. You should check your OS about multithreading and IO operations.

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, you can specify the end of input by pressing **ctrl-d**, and of-course you can do this using separate thread.

Comment: Not what the OP was asking for...