# Why fgets hangs when program closes and data piped from tail -f?

Tags: c, pipe, stdin, fgets, tail

I'm reading a log using `tail -f` and piping the data to my ncurses program.

```
tail -f somelog | ./a.out
```

It works fine except that when I press <kbd>q</kbd>, the program doesn't exit, it just hangs **until** a byte is written to the file being tail'd. This doesn't occur when using `cat somelog | ./a.out`, I guess it's because is not being followed.

It looks like the line `while(fgets(buf, 1024, input)` is causing the problem. Any ideas why and how can I fix it? Thanks

```
   // gcc app.c -lncurses
// tail -f logfile | ./a.out

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_status(WINDOW * win, const char *str) {
    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_WHITE);
    clear();
    mvwhline(win, 0, 0, ' ', COLS);
    mvwaddnstr(win, 0, 0, str, COLS);
    wrefresh(win);
}

void print_line(WINDOW * win, const char *str, int *i) {
    init_pair(2, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
    if (*i > LINES - 2) {
        *i = 1;
        wclear(win);
    }
    mvwprintw(win, (*i)++, 0, str);
    wrefresh(win);
}

int main() {
    WINDOW *menu_win, *wi;
    int i = 1, q = 1, fd1, fd2, is_atty = 1;
    char buf[1024];

    initscr();
    clear();
    halfdelay(5);

    menu_win = newwin(1, COLS, 0, 0);
    wi = newwin(LINES - 1, COLS, 1, 0);
    keypad(menu_win, TRUE);

    FILE *input = stdin;

    if(!isatty(fileno(stdin))) {
        is_atty = 0;
        fd1 = open("/dev/tty", O_RDONLY);
        fd2 = dup(fileno(stdin));
        input = fdopen(fd2, "r");
        freopen("/dev/tty", "r", stdin);
        if(fileno(stdin) != 0)    /* from ncurses dialog */
            (void)dup2(fileno(stdin), 0);
        close(fd1);
        int flags = fcntl(fd2, F_GETFL);
        // non-blocking fgets so getch works fine 
        fcntl(fd2, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK);
    }

    print_status(menu_win, "Use arrow keys to go up and down");
    while(q) {
        switch(wgetch(menu_win)) {
            case KEY_UP:
                print_status(menu_win, "Moved up");
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                print_status(menu_win, "Moved down");
                break;
            case 'q':
                q = 0;
                break;
            default:
                if(is_atty) break;
                while(fgets(buf, 1024, input) != NULL) {
                    print_line(wi, buf, &i);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    fclose(input);
    close(fd2);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cat` sends an `EOF` while `tail -f` doesn't, it just keeps the pipe open. If it was `tail -100` it will behave like `cat`. However, the line you identified is not called when you press `q`. You did close `input` but you didn't close `fd2`.

Comment: @alvits thanks I edited the question and added `close(fd2)`.

Comment: The `default:` case is only executed when you press any key. When you press `q` it executes the `case 'q':` which subsequently causes the `while` loop to terminate. It's not `fgets()` that's causing it to block. The pipe is still open when it reaches `return 0;`. Run `tail -f somelog | strace ./a.out`. See if your code isn't closing the pipe. `tail` will terminate when it receives a `SIGPIPE`. Remember, you have several copies of the pipe. Print something in the `case 'q':` block. This will help you in troubleshooting.

Comment: @alvits Thanks for your reply. Doing an strace, I see `q` exists the loop and reaches `close(fs2)`, I also see that `fd1 = 4`  and `fd2 = 5`, it then closes `4` and then closes `0` and at the end closes `5`. I can't see which fd is still opened. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: There really isn't any solution to your question. Try this as an example `tail -f /etc/hosts | ls` or `tail -f /etc/hosts | /bin/echo ok`, both will just hang until you terminate `tail -f`. In short, when the write end of the pipe is still open, the reader will exit but the control will not be returned to the shell until you terminate the producer. And `strace`ing the 2 samples shows that the process has successfully exited, `exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++`, only `tail -f` hasn't.

Comment: When `tail` tries to write to the pipe when reading end is already close, it causes `SIGPIPE` which `tail` handles properly by terminating.

Answer (score 0):

Once your code calls `fgets()` it will remain blocked in `fgets()` until more input arrives - or the pipe is closed.

That doesn't happen with `cat somelog | ./a.out` because, as you suspect, `cat` isn't hanging waiting for more data to be written to the file.  `cat` keeps sending data then exits, closing the pipe and causing `fgets()` to return either the data it's buffered and it's waiting for more or `NULL` if no data has been read.  `tail -f ...` doesn't exit and close the pipe when it hits the end of the file - `tail -f ...` just waits for more data to be written to the file it's tailing, so your call to `fgets()` just sits there.

So why?  Because `fgets()` doesn't return until it gets a newline or EOF.  [Per the Linux man page (assuming you're running on Linux)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html):

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than *size* characters from
>   *stream*
>          and stores them into the buffer pointed to by *s*.  Reading stops after
>          an `EOF` or a `newline`. ...

Comment: Wouldn't the call to `O_NONBLOCK` make `fgets` to return? Is there a way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: @user1024718 I'd think that would depend on the implementation.  Messing with the file descriptor properties underneath a `FILE *` seems problematic. `fgets()` is supposed to block until `EOF` or newline.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055702/using-fgets-as-non-blocking-function-c

Comment: that's a good point, although, I'm a bit hesitant to add select() since it will block and I'm using `getch()` to get the keypad working.