# How to redirect stderr and run in background with popen()?

Tags: c++, linux, debian, popen

I'm able to do one or the other but not both. If I use the ampersand to make it run in the background then it works as expected:

```
popen( "gzip -dc diskImageFile.gz | dd bs=32000000 of=/dev/sd%c status=progress &" );
```

And if I set it to redirect stderr to stdout then it works as expected:

```
popen( "gzip -dc diskImageFile.gz | dd bs=32000000 of=/dev/sda status=progress 2>&1" );
```

But if I try to do both, then it no longer runs in the background. How do I do both the redirection of stderr and also run in the background?

```
popen( "gzip -dc diskImageFile.gz | dd bs=32000000 of=/dev/sda status=progress 2>&1 &" );
```

I'm doing this on a Raspberry Pi (Debian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`popen` starts another process which runs independently of the calling process. No point in having that ampersand to run it in the background, it already does.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it turns out is was fgets() that was blocking -- not popen().  I used the following answer to make the file descriptor non-blocking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055774/408877