# determine if something is printed on the console or not

Tags: c

im trying to determine if something is printed on the console or not in C. is this the right way to do it? or if theres any better way please enlighten me. thanks.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char str[60];
    fgets(str,60,stdout);
    if (str == EOF)
    printf("theres nothing on the console");
    else printf("theres something printed on the console");
}
```

I did modify this code a bit. but yet it gives me no output

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = freopen("file.txt","w+", stdout);
    printf("hello");
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
    if(feof(fp))
    printf("theres nothing on the console");
    else printf("theres something printed on the console");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this the actual problem you are trying to solve? If not, what specifically is it? BTW, no. You can't compare a char array to EOF like that an expect anything sane. Did the compiler not give you any warnings?

Comment: Note that fgets is a blocking call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055702/using-fgets-as-non-blocking-function-c

Comment: no. the compiler did not give me any warnings. please excuse my ignorance. and help me get this right.

Comment: You should have gotten something like this: `main.c:15:13: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     if (str == EOF)` If not, you need to make sure you are compiling with warnings enabled. What compiler are you using?

Comment: im actually traveling. so im using a mobile app. its Dcoder

Comment: 2 hints: `char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n,
FILE * restrict stream);` and `EOF` is an `int`.

Comment: Instead DCoder use online compiler like https://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdout` is a stream intended for output. You should not try to use it with `fgets`. Using it with `fgets` will not report what is on the console. The return value from `fgets` with `stdout` will likely be a null pointer, indicating an error.

Standard C only provides for a stream of input in `stdin`, a stream of output in `stdout`, and a stream of output intended for error messages in `stderr`. These streams are just sequences of characters. C makes no provision for using them to inspect or manipulate the console or terminal window, other than to print simple messages sequentially.

To interact with the console or terminal window, you need software beyond standard C, such as the *curses* software for Unix-like systems.

Additionally, `void main()` is not a standard declaration for `main`. For portable uses, it should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

`if (str == EOF)` is not a correct statement because `str` is an array of `char`, but `EOF` is effectively an `int` value (it is a macro that expands to an integer constant expression). When used in `str == EOF`, `str` will be converted from an array to a pointer. It is not proper to compare a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Thanks! I got that. now I modified the code. its in my question. but it gives me no output.

Comment: @Dhia: Reopening the `stdout` stream as a stream to a file instead of standard output will not let you inspect or manipulate the console. Rather, it sends output to a file. And then you cannot use `printf` normally anymore, because it sends output to `stdout`, which is a file, not standard output, so you do not see it. Worse, after you close it, you cannot write anything to the stream at all. **You cannot use standard C features (strictly conforming C) to inspect or manipulate the console.**